# Make Jackson interpret single value JSON

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'm looking for a solution to this problem and I can not find anything.

I have this JSON response from an `HttpURLConnection`:

```
"OK"
```

At first look I thought this kind of response was not correct because I always saw some key -> value pair JSON. After i read that the JSONs [can take this form](https://www.json.org/) I learned :

[image]

And https://jsonlint.com/ give me a *Valid JSON* response if a try to validate `"OK"`so i think it's correct. And now my question is: **How I can map a Java class (called RestResponse) with this JSON response in Jackson?**

I try this but not work give me `JsonMappingException: no single-String constructor/factory method` :

```
final String json = "OK";

final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper()
        .enable(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY);
final RestResponse response = mapper.readValue(json, RestResponse.class);
```

I do not even know where to start with my `RestResponse` java class because it has no attributes that can mark with Jackson annotation like @JsonProperty.

**Does anyone know why Jackson does not take this response case into consideration?**
**Or is there simply another method?**

Thank you guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `RestResponse` will need a constructor that takes a single string. Annotate the constructor with `@JsonCreator`.